# Why doesn't the optimizer optimize this code?

Tags: c++, optimization

Compiling and running this code with the maximum optimization settings seems to give the same result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
public:
    A() { }
    const int* begin() const { return a; };
    const int* end() const { printf("end\n"); return a + 3; };
    bool isTrue() const { return true; }
    int a[4];
};

const A a{};

class B
{
public:
  const A& operator[](size_t) const { printf("B called\n"); return a; }
};


int main()
{
    const B b{};
    if (!b[0].isTrue()) return -1;
    for (const auto& x : b[0]) printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

I call b[0] twice on a constant object of type B which operator[] returns a constant object of type A.

Why does "B called" get printed twice? Why can't the code save b[0] on the side and run on it different functionality? (Since the functions are const functions, they will return the same result...)

Comment: While in this case it is true, your statement _"Since the functions are const functions, they will return the same result"_ is false in the general case.

Comment: Check the generated assembly, such as: https://godbolt.org/z/rxdx4dEhr. Note the at the machine code level, there is no call of `A::operator[]`. Only the output provided by `printf` is printed twice. It must be, since both are parts of the program _observable behavior_ of the code. Optimiztions cannot change the observable behavior prescribed by the C++ standard.

Comment: Not related to your questions, but ``A::end()`` would usually return an iterator referring to the  past-the-end element, i.e. ``return a + 4;`` in your code (not ``a +3``).

Comment: @ChristianHalaszovich You're correct, it was just code written fast to get to the point - but in my original code its good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does "B called" get printed twice?

For starters, because you reference `b[0]` twice in main.  And because the `printf` statement inside the operator function dictates that there's a side effect for accessing `b[0]`. So the compiler can't assume that your printf is just for debugging - it has to invoke it once for each call.

Using godbolt, if we remove the printf statements and evaluate, we can see the code is heavily optimized to print `0` three times without any calls whatsoever.

Optimized: https://godbolt.org/z/E8czPdr5W

Comment: That's because you forgot to pass `-O2` for full optimizations.  Look at this: https://godbolt.org/z/PfbqY49P6

Answer (score 2):

`operator[]` is a normal function like any other and since C++ has no notion of pure functions the compiler has to assume that every function has side effects. One such side effect is your `printf` call. If you *optimize* away one of the calls to `operator[]`, your program behavior can change (here it would only print once instead of twice). Imagine that instead of `printf` you would do a call to a database or something other important. That would be really bad if it was just *optimized* away.

Also note that `const` member functions are not the same as pure functions. `const` means it cannot modify the instance that you call the member function on, but you can still change global variables for example. And you aren't even guaranteed that the `const` member function won't change the state of the instance, because you can cast away `const` under certain conditions.